# how to prevent clashes of music player sound and background sound of my app in android studio

Tags: android, audio-player, background-service, android-music-player

I'm developing one application with background sound through out the application using background service,so problem is i'm running my app and if my music player is running - both sound clashes with each other.

**My question : how to prevent clashes of music player sound and background sound of my app**

> actual: music clashes with each other.
>
> expected: if player is running it must be pause and background sound of
>   my app is only plays.

Comment: It's kind of noobie question please go through with media player completely then after go through with MediaBrowserServiceCompat which was launched and presented by @ianhanniballake. You should read MediaPlayer as whole before implementing any part of it. If you would have gone through with it you might have had this very basic phenomenon noted in the documentation. Start with this first https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBC1FgWe5X4 then go through with it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQwe30cZffg

Comment: @DushyantSuthar Thank you for your comment, kindly noted. but this was 5 month before, i was new in android and i read it already, still i had problem and that's why i post this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must [request audio focus](https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html) by calling [requestAudioFocus()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#requestAudioFocus(android.media.AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener,%20int,%20int)). This informs the other app that you would like to play something and that they should stop (in the case where you request [AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) as would be appropriate if you are playing background sound continuously).

Note that `requestAudioFocus` requires you pass in a [OnAudioFocusChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener.html) - just like the other app, you should **also** respect when other apps request audio focus and stop your background sound.

Note: you should also always offer the ability to turn off background sounds (and with it, any requests for audio focus). This allows users to continue to listen to their music even while in your app.

Comment: where i suppose to write requestAudioFocus()? how to use?

Comment: Did you read the first link in the answer? "Before your app starts playing any audio, it should hold the audio focus for the stream it will be using"

Comment: Thank you so much@ ianhanniballake it's working and now how to resume that media player music ?

Comment: If you use `AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN`, the user must specifically interact with the other app to resume playback.

Answer (score 1):

How I resolve this problem, I just resolve clashes of two music by stopping music player and playing application background music.

```
AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener afChangeListener;

AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    int result = am.requestAudioFocus(afChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

                    if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                        // Start playback.
                        mPlayer.setLooping(true);
                        final float volume = (float) (1 - (Math.log(MAX_VOLUME - 85) / Math.log(MAX_VOLUME)));
                        mPlayer.setVolume(volume, volume);
                        mPlayer.start();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Note: Code for only stop music, not for resume music.